# C# - log4Net doesn't write to console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, log4net

The log4Net Writes only to file, and not to Console, by debug or error mode.

Even that i added file and console appanders in the config file.

This is my Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="log/SBT.UI.log"/>
      <encoding value="utf-8"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}, %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
     <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You mean app console or Log2Console?

Comment: visual studio console

Comment: @ZagGol what Visual Studio Console? Do you mean the output window perhaps? That shows debug messages, it's not tied to the console output of a program.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that "Visual Studio Console" actually refers to the Debug Output Window. This window displays calls made to the Debug and Trace classes, not the console output of an application.

To write to the Output window you need to add a TraceAppender or DebugAppender to the configuration:

```
<appender name="DebugAppender " type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
   <immediateFlush value="true" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

You'll find a very good description of the various appenders in this [Log4Net tutorial](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-3-Appenders.aspx) which explains how each appender works and when to use each one

Answer (score 1):

```
 <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Try like this

Comment: doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Its console application or not?

Comment: It's win forms.

Comment: You have attached console?

Comment: @ZagGol are you confusing the command-line console and the debug output window? The output window isn't the console, it displays diagnostics messages. You should add `TraceAppender`

Comment: Output type should be set to "Console Application".(Project Properties -> Application -> Output Type -> Console Application)

Comment: @mwisnicki not exactly, a Winforms application that gets started from a CMD prompt does have a console. It just doesn't make much sense to log this way, unless the OP wants to display live tracing information, which I doubt

Comment: TraceAppender and DebugAppender work fine.